# Javascript document.controller.setValue getValue(this)

Tags: javascript, controller

How do I get the value of the checkbox (or state, checked or not 1-0) so that I can pass it to a controller?, I've tried the following but it doesnt work.

```
<input class="form-check-input" id="wealth" onclick="document.controller.setValue('/ctx/vars/services',getValue(this));" type="checkbox" value="" />
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getValue is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `getValue(this)` to `this.checked`.
it will get checkbox current state.